# How to automatically update formula when inserting columns.

Tags: excel

Currently using IF function to add totals of each type in a row. Each data set has 3 columns, number, date, color. IF E5 = AA1, then include the number in C5 into the sum total of that row in colum AA. Likewise in column AB, if E5 = AB1 include C5 into row sum in column AB. I want to be able to add infinite data sets, each with 3 columns, and the formula in each column update automatically to include all values whereby the color is the same as columns AA1, AB1, etc

So I have a spreadsheet with date running down columns. At the end of the row I have a formula in 7 columns. In each column it has the formula = IF(A2=AA1,B2,0) + IF(D2=AA1,E2,0) + and so on. The function is that at the end of each row there is a sum total for each variable represented in the 7 columns at the end.

My problem : easy enough to replicate the formulas to cover all rows, to add the sum variables of a,b,c,d,e,f,g in each row.

Each data set has 3 variables over 3 columns in each row: i.e. Jennifer in the middle column and underneath 3 variables. I'm am adding the sum total of variables such that if Jennifer makes a blue jumped on July 5th, the total of blue jumpers of Jenny, Jeffry and John would be visible in the end colum, as would sum total of red jumpers etc.

How do i ensure these formulas update and extend so when I insert these 3 columns for every data set, the formula = IF(A2=AA1,B2,0) + IF(D2=AA1,E2,0) adds a new data set, so changes to = IF(A2=AA1,B2,0) + IF(D2=AA1,E2,0) + IF(H2=AA1,I2,0) and so on and so forth. In an ideal world I would like to able to copy a data set and insert copied columns and paste he formula update and extend ad finitum.

For now I am adding these and extending the formula manually, and hiding the cells, but it is very laborious. Any help please? Want to not spend weeks adding empty data sets and extending formula for each of the 7 end columns by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try this simpler formula:

```
=SUMIF(INDEX(5:5,5):INDEX(5:5,COLUMN()-1),AA$1,INDEX(5:5,3):INDEX(5:5,COLUMN()-3))
```

Put this in the first cell in row 5, then copy over.  The `AA$1` will update to `AB$1` then `AC$1` and so forth as it is drug over.  Then drag down and the row will update.

This will look at any of the cells, so I am assuming that the cells between the number and the color, `D5`,`G5`,... will not have a color.

The `INDEX():INDEX()` sets the range and will grow, or shrink, as the columns are added or removed.  Then end being the cell to the left of where the formula is placed to avoid circular references.

The only hard coded range is the reference which you stated does not change.

[image]

Comment: Will try that. Excellent sir, truly brilliant. Any chance you know any websites where I can deconstruct this code and learn it for myself. Seems complicated yet elegantly simple.

Comment: I learned most of what I know, by lurking here, answering, and failing at times to answer.  I will watch question I do not know, to learn new things.  One question I have assumed, in which cell are the formulas, am I correct in that they go on the end, or do they go somewhere else?

Comment: With SUMIF() the only thing you need to remember is the ranges all need to be the same size, they can be offset like I have done above, but need to be the same size.  Also that INDEX can be used to set the starting and end points of a range.  Like I have done.  Some will use INDIRECT or OFFSET to do the same but those are volatile and in this case would not work as they would require an anchor cell which would change when column are added and throw off the range.

Comment: Also please remember, that if this works, mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer below the up and down arrow.

Comment: I have clicked tick - thank you for response. I'm new so won't show here but should be added to ure value. Yes the formulas are on the end of the rows in 7 colums under the value (AA1 etc) which is used to determine which variables in that row need to be added up. Seems to be working well. In future I will update screenshot!

Comment: Not the Tick mark the grayish/green check mark below that  which you can do as the person who posed the question

Comment: um... if disappeared, if you click it again it takes it off.

Comment: It's there! Thank you. You taught me a lot about using the site.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need to revisit the design of your spreadsheet.  If you can get all data into a flat, normalized table the formulas will be much easier to work with.  If I'm understanding your description of the data, I believe this could be done in four columns:

- dataset
- number
- date
- color

This would simplify the formulas you need, and/or allow you to use pivot tables to summarize the data.

Comment: problem is I have sessions down the y axis. So for each person I need data sets running down the y axis. I need the totals of each color to add up separately. I could just have 7 colors along the x axis but there would be 9 variables for each person - a bit messy.

Comment: Instead for each session I have color, frequency and the date. Colors are different each session. So is the easiest way having all the colors on the spreadsheet?

Comment: Is the number of colors per session consistent?  If so, you could just have columns named color 1, color 2, color 3...

Comment: Or, if you can't / would rather not change the format of the spreadsheet, could you use SUMIFS in the last column (the one that you're manually updating)?  The syntax for this is SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...).

Comment: Yes there are only 7 colors ever. My problem is that I have 100 data sets at any one time. Which means 900 columns. I guess I could just do that and cope with it being ugly.

Comment: Nope, I wouldn't recommend that either.  Is there any way you could update your question with a screenshot of this spreadsheet?  Or attach a copy?  It might help me/others to visualize what you're trying to accomplish.