# Automatically update formula after adding columns

Tags: google-sheets-formula

My issue has been dealt with in here but I can't think thru and apply it to my formula

[How to automatically update formula when inserting columns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113282/how-to-automatically-update-formula-when-inserting-columns/62591380#62591380)

I would really appreciate some help here guys. Thank you!!!

This is the formula I got:

```
=IF($A$14=NAMES!$W2;$D15;
 IF($A$14=NAMES!$W3;$G15;
 IF($A$14=NAMES!$W4;$J15;
 IF($A$14=NAMES!$W5;$M15;
 IF($A$14=NAMES!$W6;$P15;
 0)))))
```

After inserting three more columns it has to go to:

```
=IF($A$14=NAMES!$W2;$D15;
 IF($A$14=NAMES!$W3;$G15;
 IF($A$14=NAMES!$W4;$J15;
 IF($A$14=NAMES!$W5;$M15;
 IF($A$14=NAMES!$W6;$P15;
 IF($A$14=NAMES!$W7;$S15;
 0))))))
```

Upon adding 3 more columns to the right, it looks up for the value in $A$14 and if that matches the one in NAMES!$W + **i** where **i** is the row incrementing by 1, then it returns a specific column in the same row# 15, be it $D15, $G15, $J15, always jumping three columns.

The 3 columns are automatically inserted via a trigger based on date/time in GAS but I was not able to make the formula automatically update via GAS.

I'm not even sure if this is possible.

Please help!

Thank you!

### I write here again because the comment is too short:

You're right!

Here's the link to the Sheet with editor access.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qkb96SgZ4dLRBebgxEiNkYiZ4sTtps-ZbBtBtE4J5os/edit?usp=sharing

So basically, whenever a new year is created or 3 more columns are added the formulas in C15, C16 and C17 be updated automatically from

C15 =IF($A$14=Dates!$A2;$D15;IF($A$14=Dates!$A3;$G15;0))
to =IF($A$14=Dates!$A2;$D15;IF($A$14=Dates!$A3;$G15;IF($A$14=Dates!$A3;$J15;0;0)))

C16 =IF($A14=Dates!$A2;$D16+$E15+$B13;IF($A14=Dates!$A3;$G16+$H15;0))
to =IF($A14=Dates!$A2;$D16+$E15+$B13;IF($A14=Dates!$A3;$G16+$H15;IF($A14=Dates!$A3;$J16+$K15;0)))

C17=IF($A14=Dates!$A2;$D17;IF($A14=Dates!$A3;$D17+$G17;0))
to =IF($A14=Dates!$A2;$D17;IF($A14=Dates!$A3;$D17+$G17;IF($A14=Dates!$A3;$D17+$G17+J17;0)))

and so on...

Comment: Daniel, to let people help you on this question, please provide a sample sheet with your data, and your work so far.  Make the sheet shared, so that anyone can EDIT it.  Otherwise each person wanting to help has to to do a lot of work to recreate your test situation.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qkb96SgZ4dLRBebgxEiNkYiZ4sTtps-ZbBtBtE4J5os/edit?usp=sharing

This is the link and I explained the problem above.
I hope this is clearer now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Daniel,  I've had a try, and have found a way to get part of your answer.  I believe the rest of your problem could be solved in the same way.  Look at tab Test-GK in your sample sheet.  Your original formula is in C15; mine is in C19.
Both update as you change the value in B14.

I've used a formula to calculate which cell is needed to be used, instead of lots of IF statements.  The formula is as follows.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(15;(MATCH(A14;Dates!$A$2:$A$15;0))*3+1;4))
```

This uses MATCH to obtain an 'offset' value for your date range from in your Date values.
Then it multiplies this by 3 to jump to the right column.
So for the first date range in your list, "a 31 de diciembre 2018", MATCH returns "1" (first date range in the list) times 3 plus 1 equals "4", which ADDRESS converts to column "D".  The row is always 15 using your sheet.
So ADDRESS(15,1,4) returns D15.
And INDIRECT gets the value of D15.

I think the same principle could be used for the formula in C16.  But I'm not as clear what that formula is doing.  Does your script put a value into B13?

Let me know if this looks useful.

Update#1.  I've got the formula (I think) to replace your formula in C16 as well now.  Except for the third term, adding B$13, in only the first case?  If necessary, this could be handled with one IF statement, to check if the data range is "a 31 de diciembre 2018".

Let me know how the B13 value is used...

Update #2.  Also added a formula to replace your IFs in C17.  Effectively the same, but used a CHOOSE function to select which terms get added together, instead of an IF.  Maybe a bit clearer to maintain if you add more years to the date range.
Try this formula in C17 - double check the logic.

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(A14;Dates!$A$2:$A$15;0); D17; D17+G17; D17+G17+J17; D17+G17+J17+M17; D17+G17+J17+M17+P17; D17+G17+J17+M17+P17+S17; D17+G17+J17+M17+P17+S17+V17; D17+G17+J17+M17+P17+S17+V17+Y17)
```

It's good to 2025, but if you need another five years or so, you can just make it longer.  There is perhaps a way to build it dynamically, but I didn't have the time now for that.

Comment: Hi Kirk,

Thanks so so much for the formulae! Both C15 and C16 are updating as I wanted, automatically. If it's not too much to ask, how could be it done so that the last one, C17, also update automatically should more columns be added?

Thank you so so much!

Comment: As far as B13 is concerned, that value comes from another sheet. 

And I forgot to mention that the C16 formula returns the value in from the 3 columns assigned for each year, so should AB14 be for instance december 2018, we get the values from columns D:F, if AB14 is august 2019 the next 3 columns G:I and so on. 
The most important thing is that it works as I wanned it to.

Comment: Hi there, I don't mean to impose, please let me know if there's any way to automate the C17 cell as well. I had some tries yesterday but I abandoned the idea after one hour. I can't see the possibility. Thank you so much for everything so far! Much appreciated. Daniel

Comment: I thought I had C17 working as well, but perhaps that was only in my test sheet.  In any case see the formula above, at the end of my answer.